# Regular Expression: Match whole numbers in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match numbers using JavaScript in a string with the following format:

```
NUM;#username;#NUM;#username
```

so for example, in the following string:

```
252;#Lemmywinks07;#27;#Trogdor
```

I would capture **252** and **27**.

However, I'm having issues building a regular expression that captures both numbers.  I thought that using a global would match both, but when I run the following:

```
/\d+/g.exec("252;#Lemmywinks07;#27;#Trogdor");
```

It returns: [252] and not [252, 27]

I should note that I do not want to match numbers in a username (which usernames cannot only be numbers).  So it looks like I would match whole numbers that are either between ";#" or a whole number that precedes ";#".

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Examples now include numbers in usernames.  I do not want to match numbers in usernames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If Usernames Do Not Have Numbers In Them...**

To find matches, you'll actually want to use the [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function as opposed to `exec()` :

```
var input = '252;#Lemmywinks;#27;#Trogdor';
var output = input.match(/\d+/g); // yields ['252', '27'];
```

**If Usernames Do Have Numbers In Them...**

Alternatively, you could split your existing string into individual components using the `;` and `#` characters via the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function and test each section accordingly :

```
var input = '252;#Lemmywinks2;#27;#Trogdor';
var output = input.split(/[;#]/).filter(function(x){ return (/^\d+$/g).test(x); });
```

Comment: Thanks Rion! I had marked yours as the answer originally but forgot that this would also match numbers in the username as well, which I do not want.  I updated my question to include usernames that include numbers.

Comment: The second approach would not. The example includes "Lemmywinks2", but the output doesn't include it. You can [see examples of each of these here](http://jsbin.com/zetoqe/1/edit?js,output).

Comment: You win :)  Thanks again

Comment: No problem. I separated the answers in my response to make them a bit easier to use.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `exec` but `match` when you want to get all matches:

```
"252;#Lemmywinks;#27;#Trogdor".match(/\d+/g);
```

`exec` is meant to be used iteratively, you would have to loop until there's no more result, while `match` immediately gives you an array.

To only take numbers that are full fields, I wouldn't use a regex here, I would have just split:

```
"252;#Lemmywinks;#27;#Trogdor".split(";#").map(Number).filter(v=>v===v)
```

(note that this solution also gives you directly numbers instead of strings)

Comment: OP should have used a clearer example - this will pull out numbers in usernames too, which OP wants to not match.

Comment: Once again?  Sounds like I'm getting a reputation!

Answer (score 1):

You could match the whole line and retrieve the appropriate groups with the following regex :

```
var linePattern = /(\d+);[^;]*;#(\d+);[^;]*/
```

Then `data.match(linePattern)[1]` would return the first number, `data.match(linePattern)[2]` the second number and `data.match(linePattern)[0]` the whole line.

While this approach is heavier than matching numbers in the line or splitting around the delimiter, it has the advantage of checking if a line respects the expected pattern and avoids returning incoherent results for anomalous entries.